# Energy storage for sci-fi machines

Tags: science-fiction, energy, robots

I need a good energy source that isn't biological (e.g, biobattery, or making extra-nutritious food and better organs)

Conventional batteries... you need too many of them
Nuclear isomer will leak gamma radiation, so I was thinking a small betavoltaic source
What I need is one (or more than one given you might need to throw more than one storage in) that is small enough to fit in most smaller animals without taking up excessive space. It should also last very long periods of time. Months at least.

The question is twofold, then splits into two parts again

What's the best source now?
What might be in the future with just a little bit of improvement?

What could power a human (which I read needs 400 watts max) for months?
What could power something of the same size as a human but with more energy requirements for months?

I'm also hoping there's techniques that could lower the need for more energy
I dont know much about energy sources so forgive me if I lack knowledge

Comment: What form does the energy need to be in?

Comment: Electrical energy, nuclear and etc isnt ruled out given it produces electricity (obviously)

Comment: "100 watts per hour" doesn't make much sense. Watts has units Joules per second. I think you might just mean "100 Watts". Also, you might want to increase that figure for the maximum expected energy consumption (rather than the at-rest minimum) which for humans is something like 400 Watts, or else your creature might just be lethargic all the time lol

Comment: You're right, I checked online. As I said I know little about energy storage. I'll make edits instead of excuses though

Comment: @Terra To help out and maybe clear up some confusion. Nuclear energy is no different than most any form of energy we use. To produce electricity through nuclear/atomic, coal/oil generators or hydro-electric, wind, natural gas, even fusion, produce electricity all the same way.  All of them are used in the end to spin a conductive coil inside a magnetic field. https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ZIQhkpvSL5E  There are exceptions like to produce electricity like,  chemical(batteries), photovoltaic(solar) and thermovoltaic(thermocouples)

Comment: Please remember that we have a strict one question per post policy. Please [edit] this to ask a single question. Unfortunately since we also have a rule against edits that invalidate existing answers, the fact that people rushed to post instead of helping you address the issues with your question will make the editing process more difficult.

Comment: From a writing perspective, this is trivially answered by suggesting you use the word "battery" to describe the battery you want to put inside living things. There is no literary need to explain how the battery works. If you want to add flavor, you can add a technobabble adjective, e.g., a "Terranium Battery." But you appear to be asking for specifics? Technically, many batteries used for power drills provide more energy than a human uses in a day. Why do those technologies not work for you? We can't make a compact battery that powers a drill for a month. So what is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

You may find out-of-the-box storage devices, which are already in use. You may describe a setup where technical issues have been resolved within current or near-future technology to increase storage density. Solutions may include:

[Supercapacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) - Assume you have an electrolyte with high electrical resistance. There is no conversion to chemical and then back to electrical energy. Charge/discharge are within short time limits.

[Flywheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel_energy_storage) - Stores mechanical energy via disk rotating in vacuum. These have high power density but are best suited for non-mobile machines. Mobile machines may need extra balancing mechanism for the casing, to eliminate gyroscopic torque which the flywheel may exert on the system.

[Metal-air Battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal%E2%80%93air_electrochemical_cell) - A battery which uses two reactants is too bulky as you may have noted. However, if one of the reactants (in the anode) is replaced with oxygen from the air, then you may reduce the volume. In addition, one of the metals may be in liquid form, and the "battery" is actually a fuel cell which uses this metal instead of hydrogen.

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't want a biological system, but no reason to throw the baby out with the bathwater.  Biological systems utilize chemical energy, and a non-biological system could do so as well. You mention how long the power source lasts being a problem, but that's not an issue if your machine can essentially "eat", converting material around it into usable energy.  Whether it's a steampunk robot tossing burnable material into a furnace, a complex futuristic system with nanobots that break down material and harvest energy like cells, or a robot covered in pores lined with catalytic material that breaks apart atmospheric nitrogen, being able to "refuel" itself negates some of the need for insanely long lasting energy storage, and the sort of chemical energy biological systems are so good at accessing could be a good way to accommodate that.

These days, autonomous systems that need to operate for long periods with no charging stations or people to refuel them, like space probes and rovers, are often solar powered, but this is somewhat inefficient for a smaller machine, since surface area would be at a premium.  The presence of battery storage could potentially make solar power viable even for something fairly small, as they could periodically unfurl some light collecting structure to recharge the battery and then run on stored energy most of the time.  If there is some sort of artificial energy flying around, machines can even be powered on that in a fashion similar to solar power.  Crystal Set radios are powered by the same radio signals they are built to receive.  This would be way too little energy for an autonomous robot, but it's an interesting example of a system that basically powers itself so long as human made signals are flying around, but is functionally useless in a fully natural environment.

The combination of chemical and electrical energy types could also be something worth thinking about, where chemical processes can be used to periodically recharge a battery or keep it charged, allowing it to function in a way similar to fat storage.  Diesel submarines work like this.  They actually operate on battery most of the time, and just periodically surface to run their noisy diesel engines for a bit and recharge the battery.  I could imagine something like a mechanical whale operating via a similar mechanism, remaining submerged most of the time running on battery storage, but needing to come up to "breath" periodically in order to recharge that battery using some chemical process.

In short, I think that considering how your batteries are recharged might be a way around needing them to last forever, as there are ways to charge a battery other than plugging in.